# Confusing about sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

when define a function, for example

$f(n)=1^2+2^2+\text{...}+(n-1)^2$

then what is $f(2n)$ ?

simply substitute $2n-1$ for $n-1$?

or $f(2n)=2^2+4^2+\text{...}(2n-2)^2$

or other?

---

What's the relation between

$1^2+2^2+\text{...}(n-1)^2$,

$1^2+2^2+\text{...}(2n)^2$,

$1^2+3^2+\text{...}(2n-1)^2$ and

$2^2+4^2+\text{...}(2n)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(2n)=1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$

EDIT: I'm really not completely sure about what you mean by relation in second part of the question, but, in terms of $f(n)$,

$1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2=f(n)$

$1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n)^2=f(2n+1)$

For $4^{th}$ series,

$2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2=2^2(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n)^2)=4f(n+1)$

For $3^{rd}$ series,

$3^{rd}$ series $=(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n)^2)-4^{th}$ series $= f(2n+1)-4f(n+1)$

Comment: thanks, I got it, the main problem of mine is the 4th series, just need one common multiple `4`.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use sigma notation. Observe that:
$$ \begin{align*}
f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2 &= 1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+(n-1)^2\\
f(2n)=\sum_{i=1}^{2n-1}i^2 &= 1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+(2n-1)^2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i^2 &= 1^2+2^2+3^2+\ldots+(2n)^2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^2 &= 1^2+3^2+5^2+\ldots+(2n-1)^2 \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i)^2 &= 2^2+4^2+6^2+\ldots+(2n)^2 \\
\end{align*} $$

Note the distinction between the **general $i$th term** and the **upper limit** of the summation.

Comment: yes, one confusion comes from the distinction between the upper limit and general `ith` term.